# ActiveRecord limit(7) - should always pull 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have the following rails query:

```
@related_products = @taxon.products.offset(rand(Spree::Product.count)).limit(7)
```

And sometime it outputs 7 and sometimes it will output less, but when it outputs less it messes up the styling. Anyway to make it always output 7 and only 7?

Thanks!

Comment: Well if there are less than seven entries in your table, how do you want to grab more than 7 from it?

Comment: Agreed. It sounds like your problem is in the styling, not in the query.

Comment: I have more than 7 items in my table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the offset that you are choosing has the possibility of being less than 7 away from the last record. Instead force the offset to max out at 7 below the maximum:

```
 @related_products = @taxon.products.offset(rand(Spree::Product.count - 7)).limit(7)
```